# How to Set Wagtail DateBlock Default to Current Date

Tags: python, wagtail

I have a `DateBlock` inside a `StreamField` inside one of my Wagtail models:

```py
jobs = StreamField([
  ('job', StructBlock([
    ('job_title', CharBlock(required=True, max_length=50)),
    ('job_location', CharBlock(required=True, max_length=50, help_text="City and state")),
    ('job_description', TextBlock(required=True, min_length=100, max_length=275)),
    ('link', 
      URLBlock(required=True, help_text="Provide a link to the job posting")),
      ('posted_date', DateBlock(required=False, help_text="posted date")),
    ], verbose_name="BYU job"),),
  ], blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Jobs")
```

Is there a way to set the default date for the `DateBlock` to the current date? I have not found anything online about how to do this yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `models.py` file you need to import datetime and then in the class where you want the date field, you need to add the parameter `default=datetime.date.today`

I hope this helps.

Comment: That worked! Just to help anyone else who comes across this post--this is the import statement I used: `from datetime import date`